# Is it VS2010 designer bug? or what I have done wrong? Designer error: The method or operation is not implemented

Tags: visual-studio-2010, designer

Base user control BaseUserControl.cs

```
namespace BaseClass
{
    public partial class BaseUserControl : UserControl
    {
        protected ResourceManager _translator = null;

        public BaseUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            InitTranslation();
        }

        #if DEBUG
        /// <summary>
        /// Initialize translation component (ResourceManager)
        /// </summary>
        protected virtual void InitTranslation()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        #else
        public abstract void InitTranslation();
        #endif

   }
}
```

Implementation of base user control

```
namespace BaseClass
{
    public class Implemented : BaseUserControl
    {
        public Implemented() : base() 
        {

        }

        protected virtual override void InitTranslation()
        {
            _translator = null; //null only for int this example otherwise initialize
        }
}
```

}

The issue is that if you try to open Implemented class in the designer it gives an error "The method or operation is not implemented." and preventing that.

The idea was to force the implementaion of InitTraslation() in inherited class.

Stack info:

at BaseClass.BaseUserControl.InitTranslation() in C:\Users\XXX\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\BaseClass\BaseClass\BaseUserControl.cs:line 55
at BaseClass.BaseUserControl..ctor() in C:\Users\XXX\Documents\Visual Studio     2010\Projects\BaseClass\BaseClass\BaseUserControl.cs:line 22

Comment: What are you opening in the designer and what are you trying to do? Where does that exception occur?

Comment: The designer creates an instance of the base class when you open the control at design time.  Kaboom.  You'd normally use the DesignMode property to check for this but it isn't set yet when the constructor runs.

Comment: ok, I also notice that if I put try and catch around
    throw new NotImplementedException(); I can also open the Implemented class in designer. But I don't know if that is a good or bad practise.